# How did we fit in the terms of pressure in given momentum equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws

[image: Problem Statement][image: The solution given to me]I was given a solution of a problem by my seniors. I am not able to wrap my head around the highlighted part. How they get fitted in 1st equation (A).

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what problem  is being solved?

Comment: No, I just want to understand how we reach from equation A to B.

Comment: Let me ask a little differently.  Can you please provide a problem statement?

Comment: Yes Sure. I have updated the question with problem statement. I have solved the problem differently but want to understand this particular solution.(Sorry for such silly question).

Answer (score 1):

The highlighted equations are saying that, on the left side of the car, the pressure at elevation y above the base of the car is $p_{atm}+\rho g (h_1-y)$ where h1 is the depth at the left side.  Similarly, on the right side of the car, the pressure at elevation y above the base of the car is $p_{atm}+\rho g (h_2-y)$, where h2 is the depth at the right side.  In other words, the fluid is hydrostatic in the vertical direction.